# Sticky header with fullpage.js

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I'm working with fullpage.js on a site that has a sticky header. I want the fullpage sections to be 100vh minus the height of the sticky header so that the header is visible as the user scrolls through the sections, but the default functionality is just to make the sections 100vh no matter what. I looked into the offset extension, but that only allows for a percentage offset and I need the offset to be the exact pixel value of the header's height. Any ideas here?

Comment: Look into [this pull request](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/pull/2420).

Comment: @Alvaro Thanks for the response Alvaro, but does this offsetTop option actually work? There's no documentation on this option in github and nothing happened when I implemented. I'm kind of confused why this pull request was referenced, as it does not seem conclusive. Was the offsetTop option actually added? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The pull request was not merged into fullPage.js. But you can take a look and modify fullPage.js core code if you really need it.

Comment: @Alvaro thanks so much for clarifying! Do you intend to put this in the core eventually? I'd think it would be quite a desirable option.

Comment: I would have to think how to do it. Right now it might lead to confusion with the [Offset Sections extension](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/offset-sections.html). And also, if it can be an offsetTop, why not an offsetBottom or even an offsetLeft or right?

Comment: Ah, I see your predicament.

Answer (score 1):

If found this fiddle:
    http://jsfiddle.net/6SQhb/514/

Which adds a header above the fullpage div:

```
<header id="header">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li> <a href="#home">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
<div id="fullpage">
....
</div>
```

With this Css:

```
#header {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #42403c;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
 position: fixed;
 height: 50px;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 99;
}
```

Dont forget to add this option:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  //other options here
  paddingTop: '50px'
});
```

You could also set a margin-top to the 'fullpage' div so you dont need to worry about the percentage.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for looking into that! So that does a pretty good job, the issue is that the sections in my #fullpage container have background images set to cover, so the padding-top set in the options turns into a big white gap between the sections that is seen as the animation occurs. I guess I could use the fade animation instead of the slide up/slide down to get around that, but that's not exactly ideal. Basically my header is 146px tall. I want to tell my sections to be 100vh - 146px tall and scroll 100vh - 146px between them, but the plugin seems to demand 100vh for both.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle in your question?

Comment: I can say it's kind of buggy, I tried but once I enable scroll-inside each section, on scrolling back to top it will not show the header of that section.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I have faced the same problem but I didn't find any solution. As an alternative what I did was I have shown header only on first section and to navigate from other sections I have enabled navigation tooltip option.

CSS:

```
.fp-viewing-* .header-wrapper{
        display:none;
        transition: all 1.1s ease-out;
}
.fp-viewing-home .header-wrapper{
        display:block;
        transition: all 1.1s ease-out;
}
```

JS:

```
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
    //options here
    navigation:true,
    anchors:['home','about','pricing','contact-us'],
    navigationTooltips:['Home','About','Pricing','Contact Us'],
    showActiveTooltip:true,
});
```